# cannot query for new bool property default value

Tags: flutter-objectbox

I have an existing database, and if I define a new `bool hide_in_main_screen = false;` property in my objectbox class, and I query it like `Store.box<TM>().query(TM_.hide_in_main_screen.equals(false)).build().find()`, I got 0 items.
If I query the whole table I see that this property value is false.

Why I don't get the items, and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this objectbox issue](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/157#issuecomment-835470375) information, I created a db migration routine and filled the new properties with default values.